# Password with at least [1-9] at least [a-z] al least [A-Z] without special character

Tags: java, regex, passwords, special-characters

I need help for a validate password with regex JAVA
the password must contain:
- at least [a-z]
- at least [A-Z]
- at least [1-9]
without special characters.

thanks

Samuele

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Remember that there are also indicators for start and end of string

Comment: Just wondering why you haven't yet accepted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the only characters the password can contain are `a-z`, `A-Z` and `1-9` you could use

```
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[1-9])[a-zA-Z1-9]+$"
```

If the password can contain other characters you need to specify what they are, or specify what they cannot be.

If you want to specify a minimum length, change the `+` to e.g. `{10,}` - which means 10 or more.